# icCube - having the specific report (and the current filtering) in the URL

Tags: iccube-reporting

If a user is working with a certain report and has a finding she needs to share with colleagues, it would be very useful for her, to have a url, she could send to her colleagues, that leads to this certain report with all filters she aplied already set.
Is there a way to achieve this?

So far we were only able to have the opened Report in the URL, if we create an application (which we usually don't use, since we have a heavily customized navigation on our own) and open a report within that application. But even then the used filters are not set in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is not currently not supported but it is in our roadmap.